# Only run the next command when find a specific file

Tags: unix, tcl

I want to check for a file after every 5 seconds if it exists or not. If it does exist then run the next command. Following is what im doing right now and its not working:

```
while {![file exist file.tcl]} {  
    after 5000  
}  
run_this_command
```

Please suggest anything.
Thanks

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me?

Comment: Should work, but is probably a bad idea if you have some UI/Tk/other events in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work, provided you're doing *nothing* else.
If you're in an event-handling environment (e.g., with a GUI popped up or serving a TCP connection) then you want to do the check asynchronously. We can do it easily if we use a little helper procedure

```
proc pollUntilExists {filename delay script} {
    if {[file exists $filename]} {
        uplevel #0 $script
    } else {
        # Call ourself again after $delay microseconds
        after $delay [info level 0]
    }
}
pollUntilExists file.tcl 5000 {
    run_this_command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this :
on the path where your file is getting generated.

```
while [ 1 -eq 1 ]; do
fileF=`ls -l file_name`
fileN=`echo $fileF`

if [ $fileN == "file_name" ]; then
<your_command>
else
sleep 5
fi

done
```